# When I create AKS cluster with virtual nodes, why it creates a VM

Tags: azure-aks, azure-container-instances

I read that virtual nodes is the way to setup AKS cluster running with ACI container instances instead of VMs. That being case, when I create AKS cluster with virtual nodes enabled, it still creates the VM for it. I think Kubernetes master is managed by Azure. Then why is this VM created instead of container instance?

Comment: Any updates for the question? Does it solve your problem? I didn't see any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this issue, you need to know that the master node is the control plane and managed by the Azure. But it also needs something else to control other things. For example, the Kubernetes dashboard and the metrics server and etc. Otherwise, when you enable the virtual node, it needs the ACI connector to control the virtual nodes. So the AKS cluster must have a VM as the node to host the things necessary. And also, virtual nodes just host the pods, you also need something to control it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I was under impression that I can go totally serverless if I use ACI for nodes in AKS but looks like it would still create one VM at minimum for reasons you mentioned. This answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Anand Well, if it solves your question, please accept it as the answer.